# Rails4, cocoon, nested forms, and has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cocoon-gem, simple-form-for

I have something like a fantasy football app that I'm trying to get up and running.  Right now I have a User model (using Devise):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :league_memberships
has_many :leagues, through: :league_memberships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :league_memberships
```

There's a League model:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :league_memberships
    has_many :users, through: :league_memberships    

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :league_memberships
```

And there's the LeagueMembership model:

```
class LeagueMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :league
    belongs_to  :user

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :league
```

The User can be a member of many leagues, and a league can have many users.

So, when  a user wants to create a league, s/he does so, and can then edit the league to add/remove additional users.  Here's the form for editing the league:

```
= simple_form_for @league do |f|
.panel-body
    .row
        .col-md-4
            = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
            = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

        .col-md-8
            %h3 League Members
            = f.simple_fields_for :league_memberships do |membership|
                = render 'membership_fields', f: membership
            = link_to_add_association 'Add Member', f, :league_memberships, class: 'btn btn-default'

= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

And the "membership_fields" partial:

```
.nested-fields.col-md-8
    = f.association :user, collection: User.order(:username), prompt: 'Choose a new member'
    = link_to_remove_association "Remove member", f, class: "btn btn-default"
```

When I try to edit an existing league, it throws a MissingTemplate error, and says that it's looking for another partial named _league_membership_fields.

What am I missing here?  I've looked through a ton of tutorials, and either I have a typo somewhere, or I'm completely missing the boat in regards to my data modeling.

EDIT:  Here's the line that's causing the error:

```
= link_to_add_association 'Add Member', f, :league_memberships, class: 'btn btn-default'
```

And now it looks like I can't create new leagues, either.  Here's the LeaguesController:

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @leauge = League.new
    @league.league_memberships.build
end

def create
    @league = League.new(league_params)
    @league.league_memberships.build(user_id: current_user.id)
    if @league.save
        redirect_to @league
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def index
    @leagues = Leagues.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

def show
    @league = League.find(params[:id])
end

def edit 
    @league = League.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @league = League.find(params[:id])
    if @league.update_attributes(league_params)
        flash[:success] = "League Updated!"
        redirect_to @league
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private

def league_params
    params.require(:league).permit(
        :name, :description,
        users_attributes: [:id, :username, :name],
        league_memberships_attributes: [:league_id, :user_id]
    )
end

end
```

Comment: Can you point out in which line that error is being raised? (The log should tell you)

Comment: `= link_to_add_association 'Add Member', f, :league_memberships, class: 'btn btn-default'`

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to sort out my issues.

The error was right.  According to my code above, the form was trying to load the wrong partial.  I added another partial, named _league_membership_fields, like it should be, and now it works.

Also, in my LeaguesController, I changed my new and create functions, so they make a little more sense now.